# flutter webview disallowed user agent

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-layout

I am trying to openning sign-in google with webview in flutter application. I installed `flutter_inappwebview: ^3.1.0` and this is my code:

```
child: InAppWebView(
  initialUrl: url.toString(),
  initialHeaders: {},
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
    userAgent:
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36",
    debuggingEnabled: true,
  )),
```

but when i open google sin in page i got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Using `webview_flutter` package you can fix the problem by adding `userAgent: 'random',` in the web view constructor. So, it will look like this:

```
WebView(
       initialUrl: 'https://abdulrazakzakieh.com/',
       userAgent: 'random',
)
```

Comment: In newer versions you should add
`..setUserAgent("random")` in the WebViewController().

`_controller = WebViewController() ..setUserAgent("random")`

Answer (score 4):

change `userAgent` to `random` like -> `userAgent: "random"`. works perfectly! but then it will most likely low end mobile interface for google page. that's the only drawback. else works perfectly fine !

Answer (score 0):

For my case, It worked for this-

```
     InAppWebView( 
                   initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("www.myurl.com")),
                   initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                   crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(userAgent: "random"),)
                   ...)
```