# Problem in google login in canva through webview in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-signin, flutterwebviewplugin

[image: GIF]

I wanted to upload pics through canva from my flutter app that is why I am using the flutter-webview-plugin for the first time and therefore I am not able to solve this issue.

Code for the same is:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kf_drawer/kf_drawer.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';


class SettingsPage extends KFDrawerContent {
  @override
  _SettingsPageState createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
  Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                ....
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 500,
                child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://shree-hari.github.io/laxmi_canva/index.html",
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController){
                    _controller.complete(webViewController);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Please Help me to address this issue .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google not allow native Flutter Web-Views to initiate OAuth.
For more info read [Google Blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)

In your case, I can suggest 3 Possible Solutions.

1. Try to Sign in with Email/Password instead of Google Sign In.
2. Use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to redirect the user to the browser.
3. If you don't want the user to leave your app
   then you can use [flutter_custom_tabs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_tabs)
   this plugin use [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) to create a native experience inside the Flutter App.

Comment: If I use url_launcher, how will the flutter app know whether sign is successful or not? 
Because, sign in is happening in browser. Is there a callback?

Answer (score 8):

You can add this userAgent :

```
WebView(
    initialUrl: url,
    userAgent: Platform.isIOS ? 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15' +
        ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1' :
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) ' + 
        'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this package, it works like a charm
https://github.com/LinusU/flutter_web_auth

In the background, this plugin uses `ASWebAuthenticationSession` on iOS 12+ and macOS 10.15+, `SFAuthenticationSession` on iOS 11, `Chrome Custom Tabs` on Android and opens a new window on Web.

Your auth flow must land in the scheme you provide in `callbackUrlScheme` property. Then just parse the callback url and implement you own business logic around signin/signup

```
import 'package:flutter_web_auth/flutter_web_auth.dart';

// Present the dialog to the user
final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(url: "https://my-custom-app.com/connect", callbackUrlScheme: "my-custom-app");

// Extract token from resulting url
final token = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['token']
```

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71297966/18723243

Using webview_flutter package you can fix the problem by adding userAgent: 'random', in the web view constructor. So, it will look like this:

```
WebView(
   userAgent: 'random',
)
```

Comment: In newer versions you should add ..setUserAgent("random") in the WebViewController(). _controller = WebViewController() ..setUserAgent("random")