# access blocked authorization error 403 disallowed_useragent when our app opens on webview

Tags: authorization, google-oauth

I am a developer of a Software Firm. We have a web application that is 'recruitment management system'. This system's login process was developed using google Oauth. Recently, we got an email from google, that informed us google will block the users when they try to login our application from webview like `Linkedin`, `Facebook` etc. We already faced an issue `Error 403: disallowed_useragent`.

We are eagerly looking for a solution. How can we resolve this issue in order that our users don't face any problem when they will try to login our our system using google account on webview?

When candidates try to login using google account from webview, they faced `Access Blocked: Authorization Error`.

Here is the screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJeWr.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You can't sign in from this screen because this app doesn't comply with Google's embedded webview Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69370491/you-cant-sign-in-from-this-screen-because-this-app-doesnt-comply-with-googles)

Comment: Update!
After adding "suppress_webview_warning=true" with url, resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google OAuth webview [policy](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) no longer supports embedded webviews. Contact app developer and suggest they use alternatives recommended such as custom tabs for chrome.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35505427)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).