flutter_inappwebview block by SSO
Im trying to learn flutter_inappwebview  but when i try a website www.pinterest.com with Google/Facebook SSO , Sign in or Sign up, its being block. im new to this flutter_inappwebview .
How to allow the embedded website to use the SSO in flutter_inappwebview ?
package link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/install
dependencies
dependencies:
  flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0

Code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'app/routes/app_pages.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() {

  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: WebViewApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {

double _progress = 0;
late InAppWebViewController inAppWebViewController;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ()async{
           var isLastPage = inAppWebViewController.canGoBack();
           if(await isLastPage){
             inAppWebViewController.goBack();
             return false;
           }

        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                url: WebUri.uri(Uri.parse("https://www.pinterest.com/"))
              ),
              onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller){
                inAppWebViewController = controller;
              },
              onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress){
                setState(() {
                  _progress = progress / 100;
                });
              },
            ),
            _progress < 1 ? Container(
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                value: _progress,
              ),
            ):SizedBox()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}




Google/Facebook doesn't allow this operation. Your question has already been answered in this Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730993/problem-in-google-login-in-canva-through-webview-in-flutter
